# How can I make these SwiftUI text "buttons" change color on tap?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui

In SwiftUI, how can I make these text "buttons" change color on tap, but revert when you remove your finger?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R0OJ.jpg

Here's what the button code looks like:

```
    LazyVGrid(columns:
                Array(repeating:
                GridItem(.flexible(),
                spacing: 5),
                count: 2),
                spacing: 2) {
        
        ForEach(viewModel.productIngredients, id: \.self) { ingredient in
            
           Text(ingredient.name)
                .font(.system(size: 14))
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(8)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
                .padding(.top,5)
///             .background(self.selectedIngredient == ingredient ? Color.blue : Color.white)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.didTap.toggle()
                    self.selectedIngredient = ingredient
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom `ButtonStyle` to do this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            //Your action code, taken from the previous `onTapGesture` in the original code
            //didTap.toggle()
            //selectedIngredient = ingredient
        }) {
            Text("Ingredient")
                .fontWeight(.medium)
        }.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(isSelected: false)) //could pass a parameter here like isSelected: selectedIngredient == ingredient from your original code
    }
}

struct CustomButtonStyle : ButtonStyle {
    var isSelected: Bool
 
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding(8)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red : Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
            )
            .padding(.top,5)
            //Could also modify style based on isSelected
    }
}
```

Notice that your `Text` view is now wrapped in a `Button` and given a buttonStyle of `CustomButtonStyle`.

Inside `CustomButtonStyle`, I use a ternary expression to set the color of the background `RoundedRectangle` based on `configuration.isPressed`.

I also showed how you could pass in another parameter (`isSelected`) because in your original example it looked like you may want to do things conditionally based on that as well.

---

Update with full working example showing columns:

```
struct Ingredient : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name = "Ingredient"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var ingredients = [Ingredient(),Ingredient(),Ingredient(),Ingredient(),Ingredient(),Ingredient(),Ingredient(),Ingredient()]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns:
                    Array(repeating:
                            GridItem(.flexible(),
                                     spacing: 5),
                          count: 2),
                  spacing: 2) {
            
            ForEach(ingredients, id: \.self) { ingredient in
                
                Button(action: {
                    //Your action code, taken from the previous `onTapGesture` in the original code
                    //didTap.toggle()
                    //selectedIngredient = ingredient
                }) {
                    Text(ingredient.name)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                }.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(isSelected: false))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomButtonStyle : ButtonStyle {
    var isSelected: Bool
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding(8)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red : Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
            )
            .padding(.top,5)
        //Could also modify style based on isSelected
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great! However changing it to a button removed my LazyVGrid 2 column styling, any idea why? It's now a vertical list.

Comment: You would have to show your code. I just added to my answer with a full working example that shows up as two columns for me.

Comment: Yeah super strange, just a single column. I must be making an obvious mistake in that case. Here's a screenshot of the code: https://i.imgur.com/0FjPWbN.png

Comment: I can't copy and paste from you image, so it's hard to say. What happens when you copy and paste mine? Could it be a device size issue? I'm running on an iPhone 12 Pro simulator.

Comment: Figured out the difference - I also have a .sheet that opens once you tap on one of the ingredients. for some reason, the result is a single column when the .sheet is added. No idea why!

Comment: If you post your code I could take a look. I definitely wouldn’t put a sheet on each element — I would put it outside the loop and use sheet(item:). Considering I answered the original question as asked, would you consider marking this as correct?

Comment: Marked correct! Sure, here is the code: https://codeshare.io/5ww4v7

Comment: Just attach the `.sheet` to the outside of the `LazyVGrid` instead of the `ForEach` and it works fine in 2 columns

Comment: Thanks for your help! Much appreciated.